# Why doesn't R change column names when I am trying to change all column names based on a single row?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to change the names of all columns in my dataframe to the values in a row of the same dataframe.
When I try this in R, it changes it to different numbers.

This is what my data looks like:

```
QS201EW...       Group      X                 X.1
1 Data
2 Area     All categories: Ethnic group  White
3 Date :                    2011
```

This is the output of `str`:

```
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ QS201EW...group: Factor w/ 34760 levels "","Area",..: 32848 2 3
 $ X                     : Factor w/ 1849 levels "","1001","1002",
 $ X.1                   : Factor w/ 2462 levels "","100"
```

I'm finding it difficult to insert the `dput` of my data as it is too large but all the columns are factors - is this the issue with not being able to change the column names?.

This is the code I've tried before:

```
colnames(df) <- df[2,]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your columns are factors, that's why your code does not work.
Try this:

```
colnames(df) <- as.character(df[2, ])
```

But you can solve your problem before it starts. Depending on how you read your data you can skip certain lines. For example if you read your data with `read.table` you can specify the `skip` argument:

```
mydata <- read.table("mydata.csv", sep = ",", skip = 2)
```

This will skip the first two rows of a `csv` file.
Furthermore, if you want to avoid working with factors (which will be true most of the time) you can use `stringsAsFactors = F`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is because all the values in the dataframe are factors.

Consider this example,

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = LETTERS[1:3], col2 = LETTERS[4:6], col3 = LETTERS[7:9])
```

which is

```
df
#  col1 col2 col3
#1    A    D    G
#2    B    E    H
#3    C    F    I
```

Now if you try to assign names

```
names(df) <- df[2, ]

df
#  2 2 2
#1 A D G
#2 B E H
#3 C F I
```

Try to `unlist` data and then use `as.character` to assign names.

```
names(df) <- as.character(unlist(df[2, ]))

df
#  B E H
#1 A D G
#2 B E H
#3 C F I
```